# FastAPI: query parameters are not editable in Swagger UI

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, swagger-ui, openapi

According to [FastAPI documentation list of query parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values), I can send a `GET` request with query parameters, e.g., `/items?q=1&q=2...`, and get back the list of query parameters. For example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(q: list[str] | None = Query(default=None)):
    query_items = {"q": q}
    return query_items
```

However I have an issue. Swagger does not allow editing this field. There is no form for edit at all.

[image]

FastAPI was installed by `pip install "fastapi[all]"` and current version is `fastapi==0.93.0`

Comment: Have you clicked the "Try it out" button on the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would first need to click the <kbd>Try it out</kbd> button, in order to be able to test an endpoint in [OpenAPI/Swagger UI autodocs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#automatic-docs).

If you would like to avoid doing that every time you use the `/docs`, you could [configure the `swagger_ui_parameters`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#configuring-swagger-ui); more specifically, you could have the <kbd>Try it out</kbd> button enabled (clicked) by default, by setting the [`tryItOutEnabled`](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/) parameter to `True`.

### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI(swagger_ui_parameters={"tryItOutEnabled": True})
```

Comment: Holly cow) For some reason I didn't think to press the button. Thanks